# Ruby on Rails select2 AJAX/JQuery - passing a parameter to controller not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-select2

I'm trying to make a Job descriptions (JD) page to compare between a choose JDs.
My main page will have a field to select some jobs, and a button/link to show the selected jobs details in a table below the selection field using select2 with RoR, as in the image 
[Job descriptions Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRBa9.jpg) .

My issue is that I cannot pass the selected Jobs IDs to the controller, and I get this message:

> Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 20ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms) 
>   ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
>   app/controllers/job_descriptions_controller.rb:81:in `updateJobs'

**My controller method :**

```
def updateJobs
  @selected = JobDescription.where(id: params[:selectJdField2])
  respond_to do |format|
   format.js
   format.html 
  end
end
```

**The main View (jdComparison.html.erb) will render two partials**

```
<h1>Listing Job Descriptions</h1>
<%= render 'sidebar' %>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
<div>
  <%= render partial: 'item_list', locals: { job_desc: @job_descriptions} %>
</div>
```

**The _sidebar.html.erb partial has selet2 field and a link to refresh the Jds that called "Find Link":**

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
list of JDs:
   <%= select_tag "selectJdField", options_from_collection_for_select(@job_descriptions, :id, :job_title), { :multiple => true } %>
</div>
<%= link_to "Find Link", updateJobs_path(@job_descriptions),  :remote => true %>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() { $("#selectJdField").select2(); });
</script>
```

**The _item_list.html.erb partial will view all JDs have been chosen in the select2 field:**

```
<div>
 <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Job title</th>
     <th>Department</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <% job_desc.each do |job_description| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= job_description.job_title %></td>
      <td><%= job_description.department %></td>
    </tr>
   <% end %>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

**updateJobs.js.erb, should refresh the JDs list when I click the "Find Link" button (I think my first issue is here)**

```
$("#div_id").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'item_list', locals: { job_desc: @selected}) %>")
```

**The JS file (I think my second issue is here):**

```
$ ->
 updateLists = () ->
  $.ajax  
  url:'updateJobs'
  type: 'post'
  dataType: 'html'
  format: 'js'
  data:   {
    selectJdField2 :   $('#selectJdField').val()   
  }
```

**The routes:**

```
get 'updateJobs'        =>  'job_descriptions#updateJobs'
post 'updateJobs'        =>  'job_descriptions#updateJobs'
```

**When I replace the controller method with this:**

```
def updateJobs
  @selected = JobDescription.where(id: 1)
end
```

it will give me the details of JD number 1 after clicking the Find Link. Kindly, I need your help..

Comment: Try it with `dataType: 'script'` in JS file

Comment: I did, and have the same 406 issue

Comment: One more try - `method: "post"` instead `type: 'post'` (along with above try)

Comment: same issue with using: method: 'post'   dataType: 'script'

Comment: method or type..both are working with my answer below..Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This what I've done to make it works:
I have relapsed the "Find Link" with a normal button:

```
<button id="btnFind">Find</button>
```

I added "id" to the first div in _item_list.html.erb partial

```
<div id = "div_id">
```

In js file:

```
$ ->
  $(document).on 'change', '#selectJdField', (evt) ->
      updateLists()
  $(document).on 'click', "#btnFind", (evt) ->
     updateLists()
  updateLists = () ->
   $.ajax  '/updateJobs',
    type: 'GET'
    dataType: 'script'
    data:   {
     selectJdField2 :   $('#selectJdField').val()   
    }
```

and I didn't need (post 'updateJobs') in the routes file.. Now, everything work fine...Thank you "Venkat Ch"